# script that calls a third party script that calls screen - how to start screen detached?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a script **'myscript.sh'**, that calls a vendor script **'vendorscript.sh'**.  The vendor script runs screen in the foreground.

I would like to run the vendor script with screen detached.  If possible I would like to do this without hacking the **vendorscript.sh** or **vendor_screenrc**.

Is there a way to do this?

**myscript.sh:**

```
# some other commands
...
source vendorscript.sh
```

**vendorscript.sh:**

```
# some other commands
...
exec screen -c vendor_screenrc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `vendorscript.sh` does not use an absolute path to launch the `screen` program, you could try manipulating the `$PATH` prior to execution. This also assumes that the `$PATH` is not reset/manipulated within `vendorscript.sh`.

For example, I've created a directory `/opt/vendor` and created a shell script in it called `screen`:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/screen -d -m "$@"
```

And in `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/opt/vendor:$PATH"
source vendorscript.sh
```

Because `/opt/vendor` is first in the `$PATH`, the `vendorscript.sh` will use my wrapper script instead of the `screen` binary. According to `man 1 screen`:

> `-d -m`   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

And the `"$@"` passes through the remaining arguments from the original invocation.